# Divergence of Einstein $(1,1)$-tensor

Tags: riemannian-geometry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold. I am trying to show that

\begin{align*}
\text{div}(G)\leq 0
\end{align*}

where $G$ is the Einstein $(1,1)$-tensor given by

$$
G=\operatorname{Rc}-\frac{\operatorname{sc}}{2} \operatorname{Id}
$$
where $\operatorname{Rc}$ is the Ricci $ (1,1)$-tensor given by $g(\operatorname{Rc}(X),Y)=\operatorname{Ric}(X,Y)$ and $\operatorname{sc}$ is the scalar-curvature. The divergence of a $(k,1)$-tensor $T$ is given as

\begin{align*}
\text{div}(T)(X_1,\dots,X_k)=\text{Tr}(Y\mapsto \nabla_YT(X_1,\dots,X_k))
\end{align*}

where $\nabla$ denotes the Levi-Civita connection.

I am a little lost at what to do. The only thing I can think of is to pick a orthonormal basis of $\mathfrak{X}(M)$ and then use the metric to compute the trace. In doing this I tried using Koszul's formula to expand $\nabla_{E_i}G$, however I just end up with some terms involving Lie-brackets of the form $[\operatorname{Rc}(X),E_i]$ which I can't seem to get rid of.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Bianchi identities?

Comment: No, haven't seen it.